# Admin Panel Call Issue in yii

Tags: php, yii, routes

this is url of my admin panel in yii

www.site.com/backend.php

I want to open admin panel by calling just like www.site.com/admin

Please Help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some ["Google it skills"](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url)

In `protected/config/{yourConfigName}.php`

```
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'caseSensitive' => false,
    ],
],
```

and rename `backend.php` to `admin.php`

Comment: I want not call .php file this is wrong:-  site.com/backend.php   I want call like site.com/admin  so it will automatic call backend.php but without calling .php file  i want just call only admin folder only

Comment: @amit so when you add this code and rename file, you can call `site.com/admin` to access admin panel